# PODs and inheritance in C++11. Does the address of the struct == address of the first member?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

(I've edited this question to avoid distractions. There is one core question which would need to be cleared up before any other question would make sense. Apologies to anybody whose answer now seems less relevant.)

Let's set up a specific example:

```
struct Base {
    int i;
};
```

There are no virtual method, and there is no inheritance, and is generally a very dumb and simple object. Hence it's [Plain Old Data (POD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data) and it falls back on a predictable layout. In particular:

```
Base b;
&b == reinterpret_cast<B*>&(b.i);
```

This is according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#Properties_shared_between_structs_in_C_and_POD-structs_in_C.2B.2B) (which itself claims to reference the C++03 standard):

> A pointer to a POD-struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret cast, points to its initial member and vice versa, implying that there is no padding at the beginning of a POD-struct.[8]

Now let's consider inheritance:

```
struct Derived : public Base {
};
```

Again, there are no virtual methods, no virtual inheritance, and no multiple inheritance. Therefore this is POD also.

Question: Does this fact (Derived is POD in C++11) allow us to say that:

```
Derived d;
&d == reinterpret_cast<D*>&(d.i); // true on g++-4.6
```

*If* this is true, then the following would be well-defined:

```
Base *b = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(malloc(sizeof(Derived)));
free(b); // It will be freeing the same address, so this is OK
```

I'm not asking about `new` and `delete` here - it's easier to consider `malloc` and `free`. I'm just curious about the regulations about the layout of derived objects in simple cases like this, and where the initial non-static member of the base class is in a predictable location.

Is a Derived object supposed to be equivalent to:

```
struct Derived { // no inheritance
    Base b; // it just contains it instead
};
```

with no padding beforehand?

Comment: C++11 mostly did away with the "POD" terminology in favor of *standard-layout* and *trivially-copyable* (at least all the interesting requirements use these broader terms).  Fix your question to use the right terminology.

Comment: @BenVoigt, good idea. I'll try to clear that up when I'm free this evening.

Comment: c++11 still has PODs though, and his question still makes sense with the termonology used.

Comment: Also, everything from "if this is true" onward should be a new question, it's completely unrelated to the title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't care about POD-ness, you care about *standard-layout*.  Here's the definition, from the standard section 9 `[class]`:

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

And the property you want is then guaranteed (section 9.2 `[class.mem]`):

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

This is actually better than the old requirement, because the ability to `reinterpret_cast` isn't lost by adding non-trivial constructors and/or destructor.

---

Now let's move to your second question.  The answer is not what you were hoping for.

```
Base *b = new Derived;
delete b;
```

is undefined behavior unless `Base` has a virtual destructor.  See section 5.3.5 (`[expr.delete]`)

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

---

Your earlier snippet using `malloc` and `free` is mostly correct.  This will work:

```
Base *b = new (malloc(sizeof(Derived))) Derived;
free(b);
```

because the value of pointer `b` is the same as the address returned from placement new, which is in turn the same address returned from `malloc`.

Comment: I am well aware of your closing statement. In fact, I put that same sentence at the start of my question :-) Like I said, there is a precedent on StackOverflow for the community realizing that 'undefined' can sometimes be very well-defined; you might find that answer that I linked to interesting. I would like slightly more than "X is undefined" to be convinced that "Y, as special case of X, is undefined". Thanks again for confirming some steps of my logic.

Comment: "either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members" ... so that means as soon as you have inheritance, all but on of the classes in the inheritance tree is allowed to have member vars?

Comment: @Martin: Only one class in the inheritance tree can have non-static data members.  (by induction, because the base classes are required to be standard-layout also)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: If it works, it's due to implementation-specific guarantees from your compiler vendor.  According to the standard, it is undefined behavior.  So a compiler vendor could legitimately produce a call to `std::terminate` for the snippet you showed.  Unless their documentation promises otherwise.

Comment: @Martin, yeah that looks pretty bad. Where did you get that sentence? (I've read a number of quotes in different locations and I don't remember anything clearly any more :-/ )

Comment: Doh! I'm blind, it's in @BenVoigt's answer!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your last bit of code is intended to say:

```
Base *b = new Derived;
delete b;  // delete b, not d.
```

In that case, the short answer is that it remains undefined behavior. The fact that the class or struct in question is POD, standard layout or trivially copyable doesn't really change anything.

Yes, you're passing the right address, and yes, you and I know that in this case the dtor is pretty much a nop -- nonetheless, the pointer you're passing to `delete` has a different static type than dynamic type, and the static type does not have a virtual dtor. The standard is quite clear that this gives undefined behavior.

From a practical viewpoint, you can probably get away with the UB if you really insist -- chances are pretty good that there won't be any harmful side effects from what you're doing, at least with most typical compilers. Beware, however, that even at best the code is extremely fragile so seemingly trivial changes could break everything -- and even switching to a compiler with really heavy type checking and such *could* do so as well.

As far as your argument goes, the situation's pretty simple: it basically means the committee probably *could* make this defined behavior if they wanted to. As far as I know, however, it's never been proposed, and even if it had it would probably be a very low priority item -- it doesn't really add much, enable new styles of programming, etc.

Comment: +1 for *fact that the class or struct in question is POD, standard layout or trivially copyable doesn't really change anything* -- in particular, POD/std layout classes seem to be allowed to have ctors/dtors as complicated as you'd wish for, and if the dtor is not virtual, the runtime cannot call the derived dtors.

Comment: @Martin: classes with non-trivial constructors/destructors are not trivially copyable nor POD.  Please don't confuse the terminology.

Comment: The standard is often clear that X is undefined in a variety of contexts; but there are other cases where it becomes clear, from other parts of the standard, that there is only one correct implementation of Y (where Y is a subset of X), and therefore Y is well-defined after all. (This is purely theoretical, I'm not intending to rely on this behaviour.)

Comment: The whole POD stuff is there so that plain old C code that is run through a C++ compiler doesn't break unnecessarily. Obviously any code that calls new and delete isn't plain old C code.

Answer (score 2):

This is meant as a supplement to [Ben Voigt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864388/167958)', not a replacement.

You might think that this is all just a technicality. That the standard calling it 'undefined' is just a bit of semantic twaddle that has no real-world effects beyond allowing compiler writers to do silly things for no good reason. But this is not the case.

I could see desirable implementations in which:

```
Base *b = new Derived;
delete b;
```

Resulted in behavior that was quite bizarre. This is because storing the size of your allocated chunk of memory when it is known statically by the compiler is kind of silly. For example:

```
struct Base {
};

struct Derived {
   int an_int;
};
```

In this case, when `delete Base` is called, the compiler has every reason (because of the rule you quoted at the beginning of your question) to believe that the size of the data pointed at is 1, not 4. If it, for example, implements a version of `operator new` that has a separate array in which 1 byte entities are all densely packed, and a different array in which 4 byte entities are all densely packed, it will end up assuming the `Base *` points to somewhere in the 1-byte entity array when in fact it points somewhere in the 4-byte entity array, and making all kinds of interesting errors for this reason.

I really wish `operator delete` had been defined to also take a size, and the compiler passed in either the statically known size if `operator delete` was called on an object with a non-virtual destructor, or the known size of the actual object being pointed at if it were being called as a result of a `virtual` destructor. Though this would likely have other ill effects and maybe isn't such a good idea (like if there are cases in which `operator delete` is called without a destructor having been called). But it would make the problem painfully obvious.

Comment: Isn't the fact that any type can have overloaded `operator new()` and `operator delete()` making it reasonable obvious? Although I have to admit that I would have liked getting hold of the size in `operator delete()`, too. When using allocators the appropriate size is being passed in, somewhat avoiding the problem in many cases as objects are generally best allocated by some sort of container anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of discussion on irrelevant issues above. Yes, mainly for C compatibility there are a number of guarantees you can rely as long as you know what you are doing. All this is, however, irrelevant to your main question. The main question is: Is there any situation where an object can be deleted using a pointer type which doesn't match the dynamic type of the object and where the pointed to type doesn't have a virtual destructor. The answer is: no, there is not.

The logic for this can be derived from what the run-time system is supposed to do: it gets a pointer to an object and is asked to delete it. It would need to store information on how to call derived class destructors or about the amount of memory the object actually takes if this were to be defined. However, this would imply a possibly quite substantial cost in terms of used memory. For example, if the first member requires very strict alignment, e.g. to be aligned at an 8 byte boundary as is the case for `double`, adding a size would add an overhead of at least 8 bytes to allocate memory. Even though this might not sound too bad, it may mean that only one object instead of two or four fits into a cache line, reducing performance substantially.

Comment: Yeah Ben, I think that is indeed the first point in my logic where there is any significant doubt in my mind. However, my guess was there was good chance that somebody might answer that "base classes, in single inheritance, must be the initial entity in a Derived object, and there mustn't be any prepadding." I might edit the question tomorrow. But I'll need to fully digest what I've learned from all the answers already.

Comment: You are wondering where the size information gets stored. But remember that this is all very well defined when there is a virtual destructor. My guess is that many implementations arrange for the virtual destructor, and/or vtables or something, to store/return the true value of 'this'. Hence, I don't believe the size is stored any where (no more than C's `free` needs to be told the size). It will be sufficient in most implementations for the underlying memory system to be given the correct address (i.e. the exact address that was `new`ed) and then rely on its own internal housekeeping.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I realize that the underlying memory allocation facilities _could_ store the size somewhere. However, since the size is implicit in the size of the object's type or derivable from the concrete type if there is a virtual destructor, even the underlying memory allocation doesn't need to keep track of the size! Unfortunately, this breaks down at the point where the size isn't passed to `operator delete()` although it is known by the `delete` operator. Of course, the implementation could still take advantage of this if it knows that its own operators are used.

Comment: I have to disagree with your explanation. While type size is indeed not stored for statically allocated items (globals / stack), this is not the case for dynamic allocations. Dynamic allocations go through internal memory manager. `new` / `malloc` doesn't request new memory from OS, it allocates from an existing pool (which is extended if necessary). In order to keep track of free / used mem an allocated memory block is typically prepended with tracking information, such as next block pointer and size. In theory `delete b`, or `free(b)` has all the info necessary to work correctly.

Comment: Also, destructor IS NOT deallocator. I don't know why the standard defines `delete b´as undefined behaviour, because - as pointed out by @Ben Voigt, free won't have any issues with deallocationg a placement new. Unless of course standard declares some special handling for new (non-placement) and delete. I didn't read the standard, but I don't think implementation details of memory managers are its thing.