# Is Qt concurrent code have undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, qt

If you write something like this: `QFuture<bool> thread_res = QtConcurrent::run([]() {});` under the hood there is template magic, and question is it valid c++ code.

1)`template <typename T> class QFutureInterface` has method

```
QtPrivate::ResultStore<T> &resultStore()
{ return static_cast<QtPrivate::ResultStore<T> &>(resultStoreBase()); }
```

(Here's [link to Qt sources](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qfutureinterface.h?h=v5.6.0#n182) to above method. )

2)`resultStoreBase` return `ResultStoreBase&` with such hieracity `template <typename T> class ResultStore : public ResultStoreBase`, and `ResultStoreBase&`
really reference to ResultStoreBase object, **NOT** `QtPrivate::ResultStore<T>`

In other words we have something like this:

```
#include <map>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
protected:
    std::map<int, std::string> results_;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void clear() {
        results_.clear();
    }
};

struct Foo {
    Base base;
    template <typename T>
    Derived<T> &f() {
        return static_cast<Derived<T> &>(base);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.f<bool>().clear();
}
```

`template<class T> class Derived` have no data, and `foo.f<bool>()` used only to call methods, not to copy object or destroy object, so the only one method which can be called via `vptr` - destructor never called via such interface.

So question is this code have undefined behavior?

According to this [c++ design: cast from base to derived class with no extra data members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518237/c-design-cast-from-base-to-derived-class-with-no-extra-data-members) such code have undefined behavior any way, but then why Qt guys wrote it in such way?

Comment: The reason is pragmatic: not all behavior is undefined in *practice*. It can be implementation defined, and in this case, is. So yes, the code has undefined behavior according to the standard, but you're not running an abstract idea of a compiler, but real software whose developers have decided to make the behavior defined. Remember that undefined behavior is a minimal guarantee, any implementation can be standards compliant and replace undefined behavior with implementation-defined one!

Comment: But any code that use QtConcurent crash if compiled with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`

Comment: You can't just casually drop that without saying exactly what compiler, what platform, what binary package the compiler came in, and once you do, it doesn't belong here, but in a bug tracker - most likely Qt's.

Comment: I think this question is asking for help understanding the code, and as such I think it is a valid question, even if answer turns out to be "it's a bug, don't do it yourself". Still, links to full original source code, as well as compiler used for the crash, would be great...

Comment: @KubaOber `You can't just casually drop` you mean crash with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`? This happens on every platform that support clang/gcc/sanitalizer (linux+amd64,x86,arm,arm64 and so on), because of it sanitzier think that static cast from base to derived undefined behavior. So before go to bugzilla I need decide who's bugzilla in charge Qt, or may be clang/gcc/sanitizer

Comment: "This happens on every platform that support clang/gcc/sanitalizer" Wonderful, but I can't divine that. This is a Qt "bug", but I doubt that it'll get fixed anytime soon other than by adding a pragma to disable the sanitizer for the offending code. In practice, without sanitization, this results in safe platform-defined behavior. You're welcome, of course, to submit a fix with your bug report :)