# Specializing an template class and adding new interfaces

Tags: c++

I [have](https://godbolt.org/z/-_x4oa) a generic template class `Vector`. The intended use is for the user to specialize the generic `Vector` and define any custom operations. For example,

```cpp
using IntVector = Vector<int>;

IntVector operator+ (const IntVector& a, const IntVector& b);
```

The issue is that there are some operations you can't define as free-functions, like `IntVector& operator+= (const IntVector& b);`. To work around this you can specialize through inheritance,

```cpp
class IntVector : public Vector<int> {
public:
    IntVector& operator+= (const IntVector& b);
};

IntVector operator+ (const IntVector& a, const IntVector& b);
```

There is an issue with this though, the slice operator defined on the base template class returns a generic `Vector_view` instead of the specialized `IntVector_view` that supports `operator+=`. You would have to overload the slice operator with the same body as the base class, just a different return type, which is obnoxious.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518237/c-design-cast-from-base-to-derived-class-with-no-extra-data-members) is a related question where it is recommends making a wrapper object, which is rather tedious for each concrete type. Is there any easy way to create a specialization where you can add new interfaces without having to redefine the type? If that is the only answer, I don't see a point in creating a generic base class.

Comment: There is usually no point in creating a generic base class for mathematical operations. Templates are more appropriate for that usage. And instead of deriving class, you can use aliases.

Comment: The only operators which can be overloaded as a member function but not as a free function are `=`, `()`, `[]`, and `->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You don't need to do anything special for `+=`.

Please correct me if I misunderstood the question. It's possible to define stuff like `operator+=` as a free function. For example, here's how you'd define it for `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>& operator+=(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int> const& b) {
    if(b.size() != a.size())
        throw std::logic_error("SIN! SIN! SIN!");

    auto* b_scan = b.data();
    for(int& value : a) {
        value += *b_scan++; 
    }

    return a; 
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to avoid polluting the global namespace, you could define it in the same namespace as your `Vector` class, and it'd still work a expected because of Argument-Dependent Lookup.

#### What about other operators, like `operator[]`?

Unfortunately, something like `operator[]` *does* have to be a member function. We can allow users to define it's behavior by creating a general template that calls a user-provided function:

```
class Vector {

    // Stuff
   public:
    value_t& operator[] (int idx);
    const value_t& operator[] (int idx) const;
    // Add this
    auto operator[](T index) -> decltype(get_index(*this, index)) {
        return get_index(*this, index); 
    }
};
```

Users can control the behavior of `operator[]` by defining `get_index`. For example, we could provide a definition for `get_index` for `Vector<int>` like so:

```
Vector_view<int> get_index(Vector<int>& v, std::pair<int, int> p) {
    return {v.begin() + p.first, v.begin() + p.second}; 
}
```

This definition can go **after** the definition of `Vector`, it **does not have to be forward-declared**, and because `operator[]` is a template, the compiler will still find it. [You can see a working example here.](https://godbolt.org/z/f1LT8w)

Comment: Hmmm, I did not know about `operator+=` being able to be free. I knew that `operator=` could not and assumed all inplace operators also could not. Is there a reference out there as to *why* certain methods cannot be free? A quick google didn't return much.

Comment: One more thing is how would one add more constructors? Perhaps `Vector<char>` should be constructable from a `std::string`?

Comment: @ktb "_how would one add more constructors_?" - that sounds like a separate question.